# Data Sets For Data Mining Tasks

Tags: dataset, data-mining

I am relatively new in the field of Data Mining. I am currently doing Some Data preprocessing algorithms such as **PCA and min max Normalization**. Our professor said we could download the data sets available over the web. But at initial level I want a simple data set with relatively small number of attributes for my algorithm, and would then switch to various complex data sets.

Can anyone provide a link for simple data sets which you must have used in your data mining algorithms? e.g. something pertaining to marks of students, age, height etc or employee data of a company. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: several hundred data sets [here](http://www.datawrangling.com/some-datasets-available-on-the-web)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Infochimps.com](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets)
2. [Researchpipeline.com](http://www.researchpipeline.com/datasets.html)

More and many more links here: [Some Datasets Available on the Web](http://www.datawrangling.com/some-datasets-available-on-the-web)

I used [stackoverflow's data](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) for my data mining class.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is going to help or not, but I gathered some websites that provided useful Data when I was working with recommender systems.

Here it is

http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/datasets.html

Comment: Your findings will definitely going to help others looking for datasets.