# News Article Data Sets

Tags: text, dataset, project, document-classification

I am doing a project in news classification. Basically the system will classifying news articles based on the pre-defined topic (e.g. sports, politic, international). To build the system, I need free data sets for training the system.

So far, after few hours googling and links from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280677/data-sets-for-data-mining-tasks) the only suitable data sets I could find is [this](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pkoehn/publications/de-news/). While this will hopefully enough, I think I will try to find more.

Note that the data sets I want:

1. Contains full news articles, not just title
2. Is in English
3. In .txt format,not XML or db

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [Reuters21578](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Reuters-21578+Text+Categorization+Collection)? It is the most common dataset for text classification. It is formated in SGML, but it is quite simple to parse and transform to a txt format.

Answer (score 0):

You can build it, you can write a Python/Perl/PHP script where you run a search, then when you find the answers you can isolate the attributes with regex... I think is the best option. Is not easy but should be fun, finally you can share this dataset with us.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to find dataset because I will be busy with the project so I try to reduce things to do. Furthermore, I do not know how to write a script in Python/Perl/PHP.